# At what point were the most current and former US Presidents alive?

Tags: united-states, president

At what year or parts of years were the most current (meaning in office) and former Presidents of the United States alive? It seems that [1833 to 1836](http://www.thewire.com/national/2013/04/there-are-far-fewer-presidents-alive-today-there-were-1830s/64588/) had the most current, former, and future Presidents alive, but what year had the most that actually or were currently serving?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

According to [this article](http://archive.azcentral.com/arizonarepublic/news/articles/2009/01/09/20090109clay0110.html), combined with [recent events](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/joe-biden-sworn-in/2021/01/20/13465c90-5a7c-11eb-a976-bad6431e03e2_story.html), there have been four times when six presidents were alive at once.

- March 4, 1861 to January 18, 1862:  Van Buren, Tyler, Fillmore, Pierce, Buchanan, Lincoln
- January 20, 1993 to April 22, 1994:  Nixon, Ford, Carter, Reagan, Bush, Clinton
- January 20, 2001 to June 5, 2004: Ford, Carter, Reagan, Bush, Clinton, Bush Jr
- January 20, 2017 to November 30, 2018: Carter, Bush, Clinton, Bush Jr, Obama, Trump

With the inauguration of Joe Biden, this has happened a fifth time:

- January 20, 2021 to present: Carter, Clinton, Bush Jr, Obama, Trump, Biden

Here's where I previously predicted it would likely not happen again for the foreseeable future, but given the happy determination of Carter to live forever, I will not do so again.

Comment: If I could, I'd give you an extra half a vote up or so for working out the actual odds mathematically.

Comment: I will try to remember to update the answer next February.

Comment: I think it's a nice artifact for people who will see this later haha

Comment: A related question is what period were there the most former and future presidents alive. My sense is that since one becomes president usually after 50 and so far never before 40, there probably was a time when there were quite a bit more than 6, perhaps in say 1920 as many as 20 or more:

Comment: Average age someone becomes president is around 55 and average time spent as president is 5.3, so that means most likely there are ten people alive today who will be president but aren't president yet.  We probably need to go back to Trump's birthday (1946) before we can even be sure of a number as he's the oldest person elected to a first term.

Comment: Three 8-year presidents occurred once before: Jefferson, Madison, and Monroe in 1801-1825. Therefore 1993-2017 was _not_ unprecedented.

Comment: There's a quite plausible scenario that would have 7 in a couple of years.  Trump is impeached or otherwise forced from office, Pence becomes President but either does not run, or loses the next election.

Comment: How plausible gets us into politics.  For Trump to be removed from office, 67 senators have to vote to do so, so it could not be a party line vote.  Also, not to be morbid about it, but Jimmy Carter is 94...the chance of him lasting until Jan 20, 2021 is only around 50-50.

Comment: @jamesqf the only way the dems are going to remove Trump from office is if they stage a successful military coup or if they manage to get him assassinated. I'm sure some of them are pondering and have been plotting just that, but let's hope they don't succeed, shall we?

Comment: Never to be outdone we currently have six Prime Ministers alive: Major, Blair, Brown, Cameron, May, Johnson. Though the length of service as PM varies from 10 years (Blair) to 2yrs 11 months (Brown). It starts to get more problematical prior to that due to the fact that Blair, Thatcher and Churchill did more than thirty years between the three of them.

Comment: There is no such person as "Bush Jr." If you need to distinguish between them, you can use their numbers, i.e. "Bush 41" and "Bush 43," or their initials, i.e. "GHW Bush" and "GW Bush."

Comment: From the OED entry on "Junior": " 1. The younger: used after a person's name (†or title) to denote the younger of two bearing the same name in a family, esp. a son of the same name as his father; also (after a simple surname) the younger of two boys of the same surname in a school. Abbreviated jun., junr., or jr."

Comment: From Merriam-Webster: "1a: less advanced in age : YOUNGER —used chiefly to distinguish a son with the same given name as his father"

Comment: [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Bush+Jr%2C+Bush+Sr&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CBush%20Jr%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CBush%20Sr%3B%2Cc0) shows it was common usage for Bush Jr. when he became politically active

Comment: @GorttheRobot The same given nameS.  Bush 41 and Bush 43's middle names are not identical.  So no "junior"; just use the full names (or initials) to distinguish.  Richard M Daley is also not a junior.  His father was Richard J Daley.

Comment: @CMonsour: Middle names are not common everywhere, and those "elsewhere"'s therefore put pretty little emphasis on them, to the point of the middle name of a person (let alone which nth president they were) not being common knowledge. "Junior" to refer to the younger of a notable father / son pair is perfectly acceptable in those environments. To put it differently, "Bush jr." is very unambiguous internationally without anyone having to think twice, while "George W. Bush", let alone "Bush 43", is not.

Comment: If Biden is removed by the 25th amendment, will that get us to 7, or will Harris only be an Acting President?

Comment: One thing you can't have is six monarchs of Gt Britain alive - in fact there is usually only one, for obvious reasons. Though between 1936 and 1972 there were two - during the lifetime of the uncrowned Edward VIII. However the present Queen, during a reign of nearly 69 years,  has seen fourteen US presidents from Truman to Biden, and fifteen Prime Ministers from Churchill to Johnson. As she said during a speech at a dinner given for President George W. Bush "My job does not involve just two four-year terms".

Comment: The one she found the best company was Ronald Reagan because he knew a lot about horses, which formed a favourite topic of conversation between them. And they would ride together in Windsor Great Park.

Comment: @Gorttherobot The usage you suggest may be convenient, but it is nonetheless incorrect.

Comment: Since I'm of a descriptivist bent when it comes to linguistics, I don't really acknowledge "correct" usage beyond what's needed to be understood.  If someone else feels it's unclear, I don't object to them editing it.